# Change number every time when clicking?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

So, I'm trying to create a thing where you click a button and it pumps up the above number by 1.

My HTML code:

```
<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnClick()">Click</button>
```

My JS code:

```
var mdb = {
"widgets": {
    "amount":0
"stats": {
    "timesClicked":0,
           }
          }

 function btnClick(n){
mdb.widgets.amount += n;
mdb.stats.timesClicked += n;
return true 
   }
```

I don't really get how to link the number to the JS object though, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be over simplifying for you...  I'm not sure what the object is needed for.   Basically, you need to use this to update the timesClicked number in your HTML:

```
document.getElementById("timesClicked").innerHTML = timesClicked;
```

I've stripped out some of your object code so it's easier to work with.   Here's the javascript I'm using:

**Javascript**

```
var timesClicked = 0;

function btnClick(){
  timesClicked ++;

document.getElementById("timesClicked").innerHTML = timesClicked;
return true 
   }
```

**DEMOS**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FamJB

http://jsfiddle.net/xFgNk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but it just does not increment with any value:)
You need a default value for n otherwise it will add 0 every time:

so either do:

```
<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnClick(1)">Click</button
```

(notice the btnClick(1) instead of btnClick())

or do:

```
 function btnClick(n){
   n = n || 1; // default value of n is 1
   mdb.widgets.amount += n;
   mdb.stats.timesClicked += n;
   // if you want to update the value in the page (in the DOM):
   document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = mdb.stats.timesClicked;
   return true ;
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but isn't the number id related to the CSS code, not the JS code? I mean, does the timesClicked ID have any sort of connection to the JS code?

Comment: ah, so if you want to update the value in your timesClicked span, then you need to do it as I did above (I updated the answer). The ID itself has no connection to the JS Code in your code, it just has the same name. If you want to manipulate a tag, then you need to select it like I did above with `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

Try change `btnClick(n)` to `btnClick()` and change `+=n` to `++`

Answer (score 1):

you are calling your function, with no argument `n`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnClick()">Click</button
```

you should call it with an argument like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnClick(1)">Click</button
```

the reason your code wont work is that when you call `btnClick()` without `n` inside `n` will be `undefined`  and:

```
   mdb.widgets.amount += n;
   mdb.stats.timesClicked += n;
```

will be:

```
0 + undefined = NaN //(Not a Number).
```